# handle one connection for all the server request

Tags: haskell

Here is the following code :

```
start :: Settings -> IO ()
start settings @ Settings {healthCheckLoggerId}  = do
  waitTillHealthy
    healthCheckLoggerId
    settings
    Server.getDependencies
    Server.healthCheck
  Server.getDependencies
   settings
   (runServerOnWarp)

  where

    runServerOnWarp :: Server.Dependencies -> IO()
    runServerOnWarp dependencies @ Server.Dependencies {logger,port} = do
       run port $ application
                    (proxy :: Proxy GSDMonitoringStreamingApi)
                    monitoringServer
                    dependencies

    monitoringServer :: ServantServer GSDMonitoringStreamingApi Server.Dependencies
    monitoringServer dependencies = streamCommand dependencies
      where

        streamCommandResponse :: Server.Dependencies ->
                                 WorkspaceId ->
                                 Handler (PipeStream (Either StreamIssue (Persisted CommandResponse)))
        streamCommandResponse Server.Dependencies {eventStoreClientDependencies} =
          return . toPipes . GsdMonitoring.streamCommandResponse eventStoreClientDependencies
```

---

Explanation of the issue :

the function `Server.getDependencies` is wrapping a bracket pattern that get a connection to a database (the client of that database recommend using one connection for all not one for each request). 
First I'm running a healthCheck which is blocking till everything is fine. Each time I'm testing the health check of a dependency each time I'm acquiring a new connection. Once the environnement is healthy, I'm getting again the `Server.Dependencies` (db connection), and I'm running the server. Everything running into `runServerOnWarp` is executed in the `-- ^ computation to run in-between` section from

```
bracket
        :: IO a         -- ^ computation to run first (\"acquire resource\")
        -> (a -> IO b)  -- ^ computation to run last (\"release resource\")
        -> (a -> IO c)  -- ^ computation to run in-between
        -> IO c         -- returns the value from the in-between computation
```

so all the requests are executed into that section and get the same connection, so far so good... Because that section :

```
run port $ application
              (proxy :: Proxy GSDMonitoringStreamingApi)
              monitoringServer dependencies
```

is never ending, we are always staying in the `computation to run in-between` (except when I kill the app...)

Now the issue I have is when the connection get closed.... all my request will return Left StreamIssue which is fine but I have to get a new connection from Server.getDependencies. I don't know how to do it properly :-( Hacks that I have in mind but I don't like are :

1) Having one connection for one request

2) Raising an exception when the request stream a Left streamIssue, that somehow restart the server to get new dependencies... The issue is that the client of the server never get a Left value and the communication between the 2 is violently closed because the server is restarted...

Do you have a cleaner way in mind ?

P.S : I hope the details are enough to understand the issue, don't hesitate for more information if necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If losing the database connection is rare, letting the server crash, and some supervisory process restart it, works quite well.

If losing the DB connection is common enough that you can't tolerate client timeouts from restarting the server, you can add reconnect logic to whatever code uses the DB connection.  I usually use [resource-pool](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resource-pool-0.2.3.2/docs/Data-Pool.html) for this.  I believe you can create the "pool" with only one resource, if that fits your database.

Usually getting a DB connection is fast, so I'm guessing it's not worth extra effort to route incoming requests elsewhere.  `withResource` in `resource-pool` blocks until a resource is ready, so active requests can easily wait while you reconnect.